# Kivy/KivyMD Screen takes 10 seconds to load on Android, 3 seconds on Windows

Tags: python, kivy, lazy-loading, screen, loading

We are developing an app with many screens and much kv code, using lazy loading template by [Kulothungan on GitHub](https://github.com/Kulothungan16/kivy-lazy-loading-template) and it is fine, besides one screen, the calculator. It takes 10 seconds or more to load on Android, and we don't understand why!

Part of code:

```
# ----- Python Class: -----
class CustomRoundButton(ButtonBehavior, CircularRippleBehavior, CircularElevationBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
    pass

# ----- KV Class: -----

<Calculator>
    name: "calculator"
    
    MDBoxLayout:
        padding: "35dp"
        spacing: "25dp"
        orientation: "vertical"
        
        MDLabel:
            id: calclabel
            text: "0"
            halign: "right"
            valign: "center"
            font_style: "H2"
            size_hint_y: .4
            pos_hint_y: .5
            
            
        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            spacing: "15dp"
            
            CustomRoundButton:
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                radius: lbl.texture_size[0]  + self.height / 2
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.width
                elevation: 8
                on_release:
                    root.calcformula = ""
                    calclabel.text = "0"
                
                Label:
                    id: lbl
                    text: "AC"
                    font_size: root.height / 20
                    -text_size: None, None
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: self.texture_size[0] + dp(50), self.texture_size[0] + dp(50)
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
...
```

[Here is a link to the whole screen code](https://pastebin.com/Bhk2PuFV)

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried building a trivial app for android and timing how long that takes? If that is also slow, the issues are within kivy and hard for you to optimise. If it is faster, the difference is your own code which you can look to optimise.

Comment: @inclement What do you mean by "trivial app"

Comment: One that does nothing but `App().run()`

Comment: (Or display a label or something to make it clear when it's finished loading)

Comment: @inclement Yes, it takes 1 - 2 seconds to load on my phone. This one takes 7 - 10 seconds!

Comment: Any solution? I have a Kivy app that takes wicked long to deploy (4-6 hours!) and takes well over 10 seconds to load.

Comment: @ErickAdam Same problem. I didn't figure out the solution yet.

Comment: @CodeClickers I'm not sure I'd really use Kivy again to be honest. Code-wise it's pretty good, but the documentation and more importantly the deployment side of things makes it almost not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

My app would take 10 seconds to start showing something when I open it. And after searching for a while I realized that the problem was in the images. I was loading images that were around `2000x2000` and the app had to load them before it shows anything on the screen because they were in the `kv` file. So I removed them from the `kv` file and did this:

```
class ItsAnApp(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        super(ItsAnApp, self).__init__(**args)

    def add_images(self, dt):
        self.add_widget(Image(source='yeah.png', height=height, x=x, y=y))
        self.add_widget(Image(source='ofcourse.jpg', height=height, x=x, y=y))
        self.add_widget(Image(source='surely.yes', height=height, x=x, y=y))
        self.add_widget(Image(source='wowthisisan.oldquestion', height=height, x=x, y=y))
        self.add_widget(Image(source='hmm.jfif', height=height, x=x, y=y))
        self.add_widget(Image(source='it_is_a_thing.qoi', height=height, x=x, y=y)

class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.ItsAnApp = ItsAnApp()
        return self.ItsAnApp

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.ItsAnApp.add_images)
```

in the `schedule_once` function I never tell it how long it should wait for which will make the `add_images` function run the next frame